# CentOS stream 8 or ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, centos, centos8

Which operating system is suitable for website?

I have 1 website on VPS and I use CentOS stream 8, Is this good or do I need to change?

I want my server to be stable and up to date and need less reboot

Answer (score 0):

Both Operating Systems(OS) are Linux Kernel-based, and both are good and enough stable.
The biggest difference between the two Linux distributions is that Ubuntu is based on the Debian architecture while CentOS is forked from Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

But if you would ask either to choose Ubuntu or Debian, I would say Debian is much lighter than Ubuntu and much older compared to the Ubuntu distro.

At the end I would say, It's entirely up to you which one to choose, and basically which package manager is easier for you to work with.